# How to get termstore GUID by giving its name

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I've a term-set called My Term Set, I need to get the Unique Identifier by passing its name. 
How can i do that? 
This is the code i have tried so far but it gives undefined
Please help me thanks a lot

Both terms.Guid, terms.id gives undefined

```
var termSetName = "My Term Set";
var locale = 1033; 

var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale);
var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

alert(terms.Guid);
alert(terms.id);
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example the methods:

- [SP.ClientContext.load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903.aspx) that prepares the query
- [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx) that executes the query

are missing.

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve `TermSet` by its name:

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession'], function(){

   getTermSetByName("Document Type",g_wsaLCID,
     function(termSet){
        console.log(termSet.get_id().toString());
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     });

});



function getTermSetByName(termSetName,lcid,success,error){
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
   var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
   var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName,lcid);
   var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
   ctx.load(termSet);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){
        success(termSet);
     },
     error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, should i call
alert(terms.Guid);
alert(terms.id);

after the 
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){
        success(termSet);
     },
     error);

??

Comment: This code worked for me, Thank you for that, But i need to make the termSetID avaiable inside the getTermSetByName function. I tried but i was unable to do so. It just displays in console.log(termset.get_id().toString()); i was unable to return and make that ID avaiable in the getTermSetByName ..please help me on this, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Follow this article, will help you : http://www.vrdmn.com/2012/12/working-with-taxonomy-and-javascript-in.html

as well look at the below code to access the terms:

```
function execOperation(){

    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

    //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_Dmxzz8tIBzk8wNVKQpJ+xA==");

    //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4");

    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

    context.load(terms);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();

    var termList = "Terms: \n";

        while(termEnumerator.moveNext()){

            var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();

            termList += currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";

        } 

          alert(termList);

    },function(sender,args){

          console.log(args.get_message());

    });

}
```

Comment: Hi, Is it possible get the id of that termstore just by giving its name..In this example i need to get My Term set ID..Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // Get Default site collection Term Store ID
>                     TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
>                     TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
>                     Guid termStoreId = termStore.Id;
> ```

this will surely work Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should have tried the following code.

```
var termSetName = "Your term set name";
var locale = 1033; // your locale. Here is English

var clientContext  = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale);
var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

clientContext.load(taxonomySession);
clientContext.load(termStore);
clientContext.load(termSet);
clientContext.load(terms);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
    var enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();
        var name = spTerm.get_name();
        var id = spTerm.get_id();
        // ... etc, do your logic for terms
    }
}, function onFailure(args) {
    alert('Error: '+args.get_message());
});
```

This will definitely work for you.

For more detail read [here](http://blog.voyta.net/2014/04/25/how-to-get-termstore-by-name-using-sharepoint-2013-jsom/)